# Why do I get a WAMP homepage when clicking on specific website's URL on LocalHost?

Tags: wp-config, localhost, phpmyadmin

Using WAMPSERVER for windows 7, smartgit and Safe Search Replace I have pulled a wordpress code from my git, downloaded a database and inserted into my localhost's phpmyadmin. My home page works but when I click on one of the links I get the WAMP homepage. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried the following in WP-Config to use the localhost URL instead of the one saved to the database but it didn't work:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://127.0.0.1/website'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://127.0.0.1/website');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, based on that, I'm almost positive that you need to re-enable permalinks for your site. You are probably missing your .htaccess file or it is missing WordPress's rewrite rules.

Go to your admin and find Settings > Permalinks. Select an option, and click "Save Changes" *twice* (there is a quirk that this avoids).

This will have WordPress automatically regenerate your .htaccess, which appears to be your problem.

Comment: Glad the solution was found. Sidenote: The permalinks are flushed on the "Settings > Permalinks" page load, so no need to even save a single time.

Comment: Visiting the page will not, however, create or modify an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have just the wrong links saved in the DB you pulled. WordPress only stores *absolute* URLs in the DataBase.

Comment: Thanks kaiser, how could I check this? I thought replacing the names using the search replace tool would take care of this...

Comment: Open wp-config.php (in your WordPress installs root directory). You can add the following to wp-config.php force it to use your localhost URL instead of the one saved to the db: `define('WP_HOME','http://localhost'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://gsff.dev');`

Comment: @MattVanAndel don't I need to replace all the urls if I use blabla.dev instead of 127.0.0.1/blabla? Unfortunately I still get the same problem.

Comment: I have tried the followin: `define('WP_HOME','http://127.0.0.1/website'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://127.0.0.1/website'); ` but it doesn't work